# Finding entities of a certain base class and deleting them based on a query

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to find any entity that inherits from `DbEntity` and has the field `DeletedDate` set to a value older than 100 days.

I have managed to piece together this code. But I am unsure of how I can go from this to querying the database for relevant entities.

```cs
var softDeletableEntities = _applicationContext.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(e =>
        typeof(DbEntity).IsAssignableFrom(e.ClrType)
        && e.BaseType == null
    );

foreach (var entity in softDeletableEntities)
{
    var entry = _applicationContext.Entry(entity.ClrType);
    entry.Property<DateTimeOffset?>("DeletedDate");

    // how do I find any Entity where (DeletedDate != null) and delete it?
}
```

I was hoping to be able to do something like this, but `Set<>` can't be used like that:

```cs
// Not ok to use Set<>() as below. Gives: 'entity' is a variable but is used like a type
var dataSet = _applicationContext.Set<entity.ClrType>(); 
var deleteOlderThan = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100);
var toDelete = dataSet.Where(x => x.DeletedDate < deleteOlderThan);
dataSet.RemoveRange(toDelete);
_applicationContext.SaveChanges();
```

Any tips :)?

Comment: Override `SaveChanges` and change entity state `Delete` to `Modified`. I'm pretty sure SO has several solutions for Soft Delete.

Comment: I have already done that. The soft delete works perfectly setting the field `DeletedDate` on all entities that derive from `DbEntity`. This code is for deleting the soft deleted entities after a certain delay.

Comment: With third party extensions, you can do that as fast as possible. If you interested in such solution.

Comment: I'll take a look at any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use EF Core extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore), note that I'm one of the creators. Install appropriate version 5.x for EF Core 5, 6.x for EF Core 6, etc.

Then you can execute the following query:

```cs
var dataSet = _applicationContext.Set<entity.ClrType>(); 
var deleteOlderThan = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100);
var toDelete = dataSet.Where(x => x.DeletedDate < deleteOlderThan);

toDelete.Delete(); // method from Extension
```